# Paypal embedded payments (iframe or something else) for rails/activemerchant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, paypal

I have been trying to get paypal integrated with my site all day. The closest I could get is:

console log:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN&useraction=commit' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

in my controller:

```
 response = DIGITAL_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(price,
                                              :description => 'test descript',
                                              :ip => request.remote_ip,
                                              :return_url => 'http://localhost:3000/',
                                              :cancel_return_url => 'http://localhost:3000/',
                                              :shipping_address => false,

                                              :items => [{:name => "#{@model.name}",
                                                          :number => @model.id,
                                                          :quantity => "1",
                                                          :amount => price,
                                                          :description => @model.description,
                                                          :category => "Digital"}]
    )
```

How do you setup embedded payments / get around that iframe error? I cannot find any good examples online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain. PayPal integration is extremely confusing and painful.

Replacing this:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN&useraction=commit

With this:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=TOKEN

should solve your problem. It did when I tried but i'm stuck in another problem.
Cheers.